# Setting enabled to true Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch. I have an index type as follows

```
{
    "myindex" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "systemChanges" : {
                "_all" : {
                    "enabled" : false
                },
                "properties" : {
                    "autoChange" : {
                        "type" : "boolean"
                    },
                    "changed" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "enabled" : false
                     },
                    "created" : {
                        "type" : "date",
                        "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unable to fetch the details having changed.new = completed. After some research i have found that it's because the changed field is set to enabled : false. and I need to change the same. I tried as follows

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myindex/" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
    "mappings": {
        "systemChanges" : {
            "properties" : {
                "changed" : {
                    "enabled" : true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But I'm getting error as following.

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already exists","index":"myindex"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already exists","index":"myindex"},"status":400}

How can I change the enabled to true in order to fetch the details of the changed.new field?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add an index again with the same name and hence the error.

See the below link for updating a mapping

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

*The enabled setting can be updated on existing fields using the PUT mapping API.*

Comment: I tried the following

    `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping/systemChanges" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
        "properties": {
            "changed": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    }`

The result was `{"acknowledged":true}` . Then after checking the same I can see the changed field is still in enabled:false status

Comment: I think it’s because as seen in your first query block in your issue description you have the disabled the entire mapping type.

Comment: I tried to enable the same  as `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping/systemChanges" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
    "_all": {
        "enabled": true   
    }
}'`

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error 
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [_all] enabled is false now encountering true"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [_all] enabled is false now encountering true"},"status":400}`

Comment: You can update enabled setting on existing fields. I dont believe you can use the update setting on entire mapping type unfortunately.